# Uploading AIS data to APRS.fi

Tags: ais

I've recently purchased an AIS receiver and would like to share my data with APRS.fi.
I've done a lot of research but couldn't find a clear definitive guide. It would be great if experienced users could advise if this software set up is correct.

1. Receiving the data from the receiver: I have a receiver with USB output. I have to use [AISDispatcher](http://www.aishub.net/ais-dispatcher)  to receive the stream on my machine.
2. Decoding raw NMEA messages: I then use [AIS_JSON](https://github.com/hsiboy/ais_json) to decode and upload data to APRS.fi. This code reads AISdispatcher UCP stream, so I imagine I need to set AISDIspatcher output to

> PORT = 5000, IP='127.0.0.1'

I assume I need to have a script running in the background indefinitely.

Is this correct? Would it work? Is anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: You might get more responses on https://ham.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that with the steps above you can share raw NMEA packets on APRS.fi.